# Selectize.js causes Bootstrap select element formatting issues

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js

Selectize.js distorts my bootstrap elements (although there's no issues in terms of functionality). Specifically, there are two issues.

1. The combobox area, like, doubles, with one part being narrower than another
2. The options area is some sort of transparent !!!

[image]

Whereas, it should look like this, if I switch of selectize
[image]

Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <span style= "font-weight:bold" class="col-sm-1">Факт. адрес
   </span>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="sandbox">
         <select id="fct_address_country_id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Страна"">
         </select>
      </div>         
   </div>
      ....
 </div>
```

JS

```
var initializeSelectize = function(id, selectize_type, maxItems) {

    if (typeof(maxItems)==='undefined') maxItems = 1;
    switch(selectize_type) {
        case 1: // SINGLE_ELEMENT_EXTENTABLE
            $select = $(document.getElementById(id)).selectize({
                create: true,
                maxOptions: MAX_OPTIONS});
            break;
        case 2: // SINGLE_ELEMENT_PREDEFINED
            $select = $(document.getElementById(id)).selectize({
                persist: false,
                maxOptions: MAX_OPTIONS});
            break;
        case 3: // MULT_ELEMENT
            $select = $(document.getElementById(id)).selectize({
                maxItems: maxItems,
                maxOptions: MAX_OPTIONS});
    }
    return $select[0].selectize;
}

vendorsFctAddressCountryId_selectize = initializeSelectize ('fct_address_country_id', selectize_type.SINGLE_ELEMENT_PREDEFINED);
```

There's only another JQuery function which populates combobox from database, but it apparently does not have anything to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but stumbled here on troubleshooting the same issue, so maybe for future users:

Check the following:

- Did you include the .css file for Selectize?
- Does the input that will be selectized contain a bootstrap form-control class? if so, remove it.
- Optionally use the options on the Selectize initialisation script:

  dropdownParent: "body",
  inputClass: 'form-control',

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.